# Asynchronous page validation - how to check values after $http response

Tags: angularjs, asynchronous

In my controller I am checking for a big **form** with lot's of **inputs** in order to generate a new page (as JSON file) once everything is filled in. I collect the input validations manually with an object `$scope.validation`. For example:

```
if (!$scope.title) {
    $scope.validation.title.error = true;
}
```

Then I display appropriate content when something is missing or needs to be changed. I'm checking it with:

```
if ($scope.validation.title.error) { /* and many more here */
    $scope.formValid = false; // form is invalid if at least one error occurred
}
```

One of my inputs collects links (URLs) to other pages.

```
<div ng-repeat="parent in parents">
    <input ng-model="parent.url" placeholder="URL" type="text" />
</div>
```

After which, **I need to check if those pages exist**. The way I am doing it is with:

```
$http.get(url).then((res)=>{
    /* page exists */
    $scope.validation.parents.error = false;
}. (err)=>{
    /* page doesn't exists */
    $scope.validation.parents.error = true;
});
```

(In fact this is happening in a loop, so the asynchronous response is even slower)

Because it needs to wait for the data to arrive, it can't check `$scope.validation.parents.error` in time along with other validations.

How do I check this value asynchronously so that something like this works:

```
if ($scope.validation.title.error || /* and many more here */
  $scope.validation.parents.error) { 
    $scope.formValid = false;
}
```

---

Any alternative ideas for this kind of page validation are accepted

Comment: Asynchronous validation is done with the [`$asyncValidators` API](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController#$asyncValidators).

Comment: @georgeawg, I'm not familiar with this, since I'm doing manual validations (checking whether pages exist, etc.) I don't know if this will help me

Answer (score 0):

Asynchronous validation is done with the [`$asyncValidators` API](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController#$asyncValidators).

From the Docs:

> ## `$asyncValidators`
>
> A collection of validations that are expected to perform an asynchronous validation (e.g. a HTTP request). The validation function that is provided is expected to return a promise when it is run during the model validation process. Once the promise is delivered then the validation status will be set to true when fulfilled and false when rejected. When the asynchronous validators are triggered, each of the validators will run in parallel and the model value will only be updated once all validators have been fulfilled. As long as an asynchronous validator is unfulfilled, its key will be added to the controllers `$pending` property. Also, all asynchronous validators will only run once all synchronous validators have passed.
>
> Please note that if $http is used then it is important that the server returns a success HTTP response code in order to fulfill the validation and a status level of `4xx` in order to reject the validation.
>
> ```
> ngModel.$asyncValidators.uniqueUsername = function(modelValue, viewValue) {
>   var value = modelValue || viewValue;
>
>   // Lookup user by username
>   return $http.get('/api/users/' + value).
>      then(function resolved() {
>        //username exists, this means validation fails
>        return $q.reject('exists');
>      }, function rejected() {
>        //username does not exist, therefore this validation passes
>        return true;
>      });
> };
> ```
>
> [— AngularJS `ngModelController` API Reference - `$asyncValidators`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController#$asyncValidators)

For additional information, see [AngularJS Developer Reference - Custom Validation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms#custom-validation)

Comment: I'm checking the validation on ng-click="check()" within a controller. $asyncValidators is used in a directive and calls $http.get() every time I type a letter (for the URL to be checked). It doesn't look like this is what I need, unless there is a way to use it in a controller after a check() function call.